# Best practice for only appending/finding elements that have an attribute or have text that contains a certain string with Python BS4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, async-await

Current discord.py (async.io) code to print a link for a random NY Times article.

```
@client.command()
async def news(ctx):
    url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/section/us'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    articles = soup.find_all('a')
    newslist = []
    for article in articles:
        newslist.append(article['href'])
    news = random.choice(newslist)
    while "2020" not in news:
        news = random.choice(newslist)
    else:
        await ctx.send('https://www.nytimes.com' + news)
```

Since every link in the page is being appended to newslist, the check for "2020", which means it's an article, is being done right before the print / await ctx.send. Is there any way to do a find_all('a') that only finds links that contain "2020", or a way to only append links that contain "2020"? Would these methods be more efficient?

Comment: Yes, there is probably a way. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

r = requests.get("https://www.nytimes.com/section/us")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

urls = []
for item in soup.findAll("a", href=re.compile("2020")):
    item = item.get("href")
    if not item.startswith("http"):
        item = f"https://www.nytimes.com{item}"
    else:
        pass
    if item not in urls:
        urls.append(item)
        print(item)
```

Output:

```
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/18/us/coronavirus-immigrants.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/18/us/coronavirus-nebraska-biocontainment.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/18/us/coronavirus-janitors-cleaners.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/18/us/small-business-coronavirus-charlotte.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/19/us/politics/coronavirus-heaven-frilot-mark-frilot.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/19/us/politics/coronavirus-state-department-travel.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/19/us/politics/coronavirus-congress-voting.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/19/us/coronavirus-foster-pets.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/19/books/molly-brodak-dies.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/19/us/politics/joe-biden-vice-president.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/19/us/coronavirus-location-tracking.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/19/climate/us-flood-season-forescast.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/19/health/coronavirus-masks-shortage.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/19/health/coronavirus-travel-ban.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/19/arts/mal-sharpe-dead.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/19/business/coronavirus-unemployment-states.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/19/us/work-from-home-mothers-coronavirus-covid19.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/19/us/politics/1000-checks-coronavirus-stimulus.html
https://www.nytimes.com/news-event/2020-election
```